# fill up NaN using columns of other dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I notice that most of the areas are not present in area column and they are present in city column so infornt of city I want to fillup pincodes in df1

I have two dataframes

```
Df1 = 
City          area          Pincode
Pune        Bibwewadi       159963
Mumbai      Bandra(W)       123456
Bibwewadi           
Bandra(E)
Badlapur     Badlapur       752147
Bhiwandi     Bhiwandi       784512
```

```
Df2 = 
Area        Pincode
Bibwewadi   159963
Badlapur    752147
Parvati     784596
Baner       411007
Bandra(E)   326598
```

As in df1 some areas are in city column I want to fillup NaN values of pincode column in df1 withe help of df2  using pandas

Expected output

```
df1=
City          area          Pincode
Pune        Bibwewadi       159963
Mumbai      Bandra(W)       123456
Bibwewadi                   159963
Bandra(E)                   326598
Badlapur     Badlapur       752147
Bhiwandi     Bhiwandi       784512
```

Comment: please, show an example of your input and  expect output dataframe

Comment: df4['pcode'] = df4['pcode'].fillna(df4.groupby('city')['pcode'].transform('first')) but this is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html),
This option may be useful if the values ​​are not `NaN` values.:

```
c=df1['Pincode'].isnull()|df1['Pincode'].eq('')
df1=df1.replace('Bandra – E','Bandra(E)')
df1.loc[c,'Pincode']=df1.loc[c,'City'].map(df2.set_index('Area')['Pincode'])
print(df1)


        City       area   Pincode
0       Pune  Bibwewadi  159963.0
1     Mumbai  Bandra(W)  123456.0
2  Bibwewadi       None  159963.0
3  Bandra(E)       None  326598.0
4   Badlapur   Badlapur  752147.0
5   Bhiwandi   Bhiwandi  784512.0
```

or [Series.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

```
df1=df1.replace('Bandra – E','Bandra(E)').set_index('City')
df1['Pincode']=df1['Pincode'].fillna(df2.set_index('Area')['Pincode'])
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Note:

Check well what type of missing values ​​you have in the dataframe, as well as the column labels and the replaced value:`'Bandra – E'`

Comment: thanks but getting this error

cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: getting this error using pandas.series.map 
KeyError: 'City'

Comment: your column name may not be City. Check the nemae of columns using: df1.columns and df2.columns. 
 Aprende a pronunciar
I have used the names you have shown in the question but they could be different or contain spaces

Comment: add to your answer the result of `df1.columns` and `df2.columns`

Comment: df1 column names are city,area,pincode and df2 column names are area and pincode

Comment: You have to take into account the upper and lower case. Surely your mistake is due to it.